# How to configure authentication providers per clientId in spring oauth authorization service

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to determine if I could use a different authentication provider for each client ID within the same spring oauth2 authorization service.

In particular, I want to allow resource owner password token grant for external users loging into our corporate websites, and implicit grant for corporate users. Corporate users are stored in our corporate Active Directory server, while external users are stored in a separate LDAP server.

Is it possible to somehow bind the AuthenticationManager to the clientId?